# Python: Search for the specific strings in a text file consisting of multiple columns

Tags: python

I have a text file which is tab-delimited (every column is responsible for a certain component.):

```
  1 (who?)        2 (age)        3 (Does what?)        4 )(where lives?)
A    Dog             4                 Walks           Lives in a box
B   Parrot           2                 Eats            Lives in a cage
C   Cat              3                 Sleeps          Lives in a house
```

User has to choose between two option of finding all the information about the animal. User can either type his guess into the first column or the fourth:

```
1=Cat*
```

OR

```
4=Live in a box**
```

And if there is a match it prints the whole line.

- in the first case, if user decides to use first column(who?) to find information about the animal in would show:

  ```
  Cat              3                 Sleeps          Lives in a house
  ```
- in the second case, if user decides to use fourth column(where lives?) to find information about the animal in would show:

  ```
  Dog             4                 Walks           Lives in a box
  ```

What I need is to find a proper function that will search for an animal. I tried using search() and match() but to no avail.

```
                        **EDIT after codesparkle's advice**
```

I can't seem to integrate the advised function into my program. I am particularly confused with line[column-1] bit. I tried to "play" with this function but I could not come up with anything useful. So here is the real piece of code that I need complete.

```
while True:
    try:
        OpenFile=raw_input(str("Please enter a file name: ")) 
        infile=open(OpenFile,"r")
        contents=infile.readlines()
        infile.close()

        user_input = raw_input(str("Enter A=<animal> for animal search or B=<where lives?> for place of living search: \n"))

        if user_input.startswith("A="):
            def find_animal(user_input,column):
                return next(("\t".join(line) for line in contents
                             if line[column-1]==user_input),None)
            find_animal(user_input[1:]) 
            print str((find_animal(user_input[1:], "WHO?"))) # I messed up the first time and gave numeric names to the columns. In reality they should have been words that indicate the proper name of the column. In this case it is WHO- the first column which signifies the animal.

        else:
            print "Unknown option!"


    except IOError:
        print "File with this name does not exist!"
```

Comment: Please share the code you already tried using `search` and `match` and what went wrong with that code, so that answerers can show you how to adapt your code to get the result you want.

Comment: I would love to but it is basically variable.re.search() and then I can't really understand what happens in brackets. I used python documents but it still seems complicated. http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject

Comment: Any code you already wrote will make it easier to answer your question, along with the output you got when you run it. If you can edit your post to include your current code example and its output you increase the likelihood that someone will attempt to answer your question.

Comment: Alright, thank you I'll keep it in mind for later.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input looks like this (the example you posted contained spaces, not tabs):

```
Dog 4   Walks   Lives in a box
Parrot  2   Eats    Lives in a cage
Cat 3   Sleeps  Lives in a house
```

You can take the following approach:

1. Open the file and read the lines, splitting them by tab and removing the newline characters.
2. Create a function that returns the first line whose requested column contains the search term. In this example, `None` is returned if nothing is found.

---

```
with open('input.txt') as input_file:
    lines = [line.rstrip().split('\t')
             for line in input_file.readlines()]

def find_animal(search_term, column):
    return next(('\t'.join(line) for line in lines
                 if line[column-1] == search_term), None)

print(find_animal('Cat', 1))
print(find_animal('Lives in a box', 4))
```

Comment: Hey, sorry that it took me so long. My hdd broke down and I had to fix my laptop. Can you please take a look at my edit with your function and help me find out what I am doing wrong?